# Accessing database connection string using app.config in C# winform

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, database-connection, app-config

I can't seem to be able to access the app.config database connection string in my c# winforms app.

app.config code

```
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDBConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MySQLServerDB; Integrated Security=true" />
   </connectionStrings>
```

C# code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyDBConnectionString"];
```

When I try the C# code, I get a message:
*Warning    1   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings' is obsolete: '
This method is obsolete, it has been replaced by System.Configuration!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings'*

However, when I try to use:

```
conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyDBConnectionString"];
```

I get an error: *Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement*

Comment: Usually I get that error when I don't put a `()` at the end of the line of code... (**This is old, but I still like to comment**)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `ConfigurationManager` instead of `ConfigurationSettings`. It has a `ConnectionStrings` property that you should use for connection strings in the `connectionStrings` section:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using the ConnectionStrings collection, not the AppSettings.

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 5):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=MY-PC;Initial Catalog=DB2013;User ID=sa;Password=MYSQL123" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

```cs
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace OnlineDelete_W2013
{
    public partial class CommodityEdit : Form
    {
       SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
    
        public CommodityEdit()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
          
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               MyConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnection"].ToString()))
{
....(your code here) ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
try
{
    conn.Open();                
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;                    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers stating to use the line

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

are correct.

If an error appears stating that ConfigurationManager does not exist, it's because your project hasn't referenced **System.Configuration**.

To do that in .NET Framework, in **Solution Explorer**, in the project where you want to use this line of code, right-click in **References**, choose **Add Reference...**, then choose **Assemblies** on the left-side and **Framework** under it. Pick **System.Configuration** on the list and click **Ok**.

Answer (score 0):

About this:

> I get an error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

I just declared a var like this and solved the problem:

```
var strConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code. this is as you are expecting:

```
SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```