# Connection string in C# Window application

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, winforms

In window application, i am trying to work with database, how to write connection string in app.config. The below is connection string in app.config

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings >
  <add key ="mycon" 
      value ="server=192*****;database=*****;
      uid=**;pwd=*****;"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Code to connect database:

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
   ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["mycon"].ToString()); con.Open(); 
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Usp_chat_login", con);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
   cmd.Parameters["@userid"].Value = textBox1.Text;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
  cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = textBox2.Text;
  int reslt =  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  con.Close();
  if (reslt > 0)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Yes");
    } 
  else
     {
          MessageBox.Show("No");

     }
```

Every time i am getting `reslt=-1`, even if i pass correct credentials

Comment: You're storing plain-text passwords, aren't you? Limited to only 20 characters? /facepalm

Comment: How to store and access connection string in win app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476103/accessing-database-connection-string-using-app-config-in-c-sharp-winform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Every time i am getting reslt=-1, even if i pass correct credentials

This has nothing to do with the credentials, nor does it pertain to the config file. If authentication/authorization to the database failed, an exception would be thrown.

The problem is likely in your `Usp_chat_login` procedure.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) for `ExecuteNonQuery()`:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

**Other notes:**

- Types which implement `IDisposable` should be disposed of, especially types which interact with unmanaged resources (e.g. database connections). A simple way to do this is to wrap the instances of these types in a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).
- Plain-text passwords are considered insecure/irresponsible in *any* application.

Answer (score 0):

Write it in App.XAML

```
 public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        string connectionStr = "Data Source=system\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=DBName; user id=sa; password=test123;";
        Application.Current.Properties["conStr"] = connectionStr;
    }
}
```

and Access it in main form

```
static string strCon = Application.Current.Properties["conStr"].ToString();
```