# How to make a remote connection with SQL Server 2008 with ADO.NET entity Data model from C# winform

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, winforms

I have built a window form application and I use ADO.NET entity Data model to make connection with my local database and it work good with my own PC (the database and application in one PC).

Now I need the application to be used by many users 3 or 4. I have no idea how  to install my database on the server and whether ADO.NET entity Data model will work again. I use SQL Server 2008 and C# window Form. Please I am waiting to hear what your suggestion will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need to do is just change the `Data Source` value in your connection string.

Follow the below Steps:

**Step 1:** Install and Maintain Your `Database` in your server machine.

**Step 2 :** Specify your databse Server `HostName/IP Address` in your Connection String as below:

```
String   connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Intial Catalog=DatabaseName;UID=userID;Password=password;Integrated Security=True;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have host your database on server

Get server ip,username,password for the database

change your connection string

replace server name ,username,password

```
Data Source=serverip;Initial Catalog=dbname;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password
```

then this will be goto server database

Answer (score 0):

Add app.config file to your project and specify the connection string in there. Then access the config file using c#

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDBConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MySQLServerDB; Integrated Security=true" />
   </connectionStrings>
```

in c#

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Source [Accessing database connection string using app.config in C# winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476103/accessing-database-connection-string-using-app-config-in-c-sharp-winform)