# How can I have the SQL connection string in one place?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Currently I have the SQL connection string in every form in my application, like this:

```
Dim cnx As New SqlConnection("Server = SERVERNAME\SQLSERVEREXPRESS; " &
                             "Database = DatabaseName; " &
                             "Trusted_Connection = True;")
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim sdr As SqlDataReader
```

The problem is when I need to change it, I have to do it in every form in the application. What are some better ways to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT

I ended up using Christopherous 5000 answer translated to VB.NET:

```
Public Shared Function GetConnectionString(name As String) As String
    Dim connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(name)

    If connectionString Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString.ConnectionString) Then
        Throw New ConfigurationErrorsException(String.Format("No connection string for '{0}' found", name))
    End If

    Return connectionString.ConnectionString
End Function
```

Comment: You mean like a configuration file? Search for App.config or web.config.

Comment: connection.config if you want to secure/encrypt it. otherwise web.config or global.asa if classic.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx for docs

Comment: xQbert - you can encrypt sections of the web.config as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the web.config file to store connection string (these can be encrypted if needed)

I use a helper class with this static method when needing a connection;

```
public static string GetConnectionString(string name)
        {
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name];

            if (connectionString == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString.ConnectionString))
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(string.Format("No connection string for '{0}' found", name));

            return connectionString.ConnectionString;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

App.config or Web.config depending on project would make sense.  If you won't be keeping your compiled code private than you'd want to bake your own implementation.  [Accessing database connection string using app.config in C# winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476103/accessing-database-connection-string-using-app-config-in-c-sharp-winform)