# One datagridview and data from two databases and usb. How to start?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I have to do a windows form that looks like this: http://s28.postimg.org/y9ezkreod/datagridview_plan.png
This is just a view plan but as you can see I'd like to have one datagridview and data from multiple sources to specific columns. Will somebody deliver some links or materials to read because I don't know how to start and what to search?
Data from the SQL server will be:

Id_model|| Model_name ||Ordered_added_features (of device)|| Serial_code (of added features)

MySQL:

|| Date_of_last_soft_update|| two more...

USB:

Instaled_sofrware_Id|| If SD card is present|| ...

Comment: The first thing you need is to know what will be the joining keys/IDs. The 2nd is [how to ask a good question here..](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm form Eastern Europe and not fluent in English. I often can't express what is on my mind well enough. Frankly, I don't know why are you guys insted of helping, pointing language mistakes and posting errors...

Comment: This is not about language mistakes, this is about the format of this site. When you hit a coding problem we'll help you but while you are planning this is not a good place to ask for help. BTW, I gave you an important hint!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "Code-It-For-Me" Site so may you give us some example code and I´m sure somebody will help you!

For Sql- and MySql-Connection are following links helpful:

SQL:[Sql-Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476103/accessing-database-connection-string-using-app-config-in-c-sharp-winform)

MySql:[MySql-Connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html)

You have to use a "splitcontainer" to spread your screen/form like the picture.

I hope this solved your problem! have a nice day!