# Is it possible to make connection string dynamically change whenever a C# application is installed in another computer?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, configuration, app-config

I just deployed the project I created and when I shared the setup file and ran the application in another computer the database did not work. I think I know what the problem is, but I do not have the slightest idea on how to fix it because I am new to SQL.

I think the problem is the connection string:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=X:\Documents\SMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

Can someone tell me how fix it please? the application is a project for my course. Any help will do, thanks.

Comment: Where will the data file be located? If it could be any random folder then the application won't magically work that out for itself. If it's a common location, e.g. the same folder as the EXE or the user's Documents folder, then there are ways to code that such that it will resolve automatically at run time. You need to explain the details to us if you want us to explain the details to you though.

Comment: You should outsource the ConnectionString into a configuration file. Depending your used framework you have differen options. Check for example this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476103/accessing-database-connection-string-using-app-config-in-c-sharp-winform

Comment: You might find some help here: https://blog.elmah.io/the-ultimate-guide-to-connection-strings-in-web-config/

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding all of you. The data will be in the same folder as the EXE file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question title, yes We can get different connection strings.
All you need to do is define the connection string in some config file like App.Config or Web.Config or AppSettings.Json (Depending on the kind of application and target .net framework version).

and then read the respective configuration based on the environment or machine.

Refer these https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configuration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-app-config-file?view=vs-2022

Comment: Hi thanks for responding I have created an App.Config file and defined the string in it, but what do you mean by reading  the respective configuration based on the environment or machine?

Comment: @maprisoka so you could have different configurations in app.config files based on environment or machine like development, QA or production.